# Error: Exit Code 134 while executing a c++ program for a specific input

Tags: c++, exit-code

My code is not running for input like

```
6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

But it is running for other inputs like

```
7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

When I run the program for the former input it shows exit code 134
But when I run for latter input it works fine with the output as expected.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int helper(int* arr, int n, int pos) {
  int r = pos + 2, l = pos - 2, ans = 0;
  while (r <= n) {
    ans += arr[r] * arr[r - 1] * arr[pos];
    r++;
  }
  while (l >= 0) {
    ans += arr[l] * arr[l + 1] * arr[pos];
    l--;
  }
  if (pos != 0 && pos != n) ans += arr[pos] * arr[0] * arr[n];
  return ans;
}
int matrixChainMultiplication(int* arr, int n) {
  int ans = INT_MAX;
  for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    ans = min(ans, helper(arr, n, i));
  }
  return ans;
}

int main() {
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  int* arr = new int[n];

  for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    cin >> arr[i];
  }

  cout << matrixChainMultiplication(arr, n);

  delete[] arr;
}
```

Comment: When you run it using a debugger, what is the *first* thing it does wrong?

Comment: Exit code 134 means that the program was aborted by a SIGABRT signal.

Comment: What is the purpose of your program? What does it do?

Comment: When I ran your code, it seems that you have a buffer overflow in `helper()`.

Comment: When using a debugger and the execution of the program returns to main function after calling the matrixChainMultiplication function it show the SIGABRT signal.

Comment: Does your program return the correct outputs?

Comment: @AyushVerma Were you able to solve the issue? If so, did any answers below help?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is exiting with code 134, which means it received a `SIGABRT` signal. After debugging your code, I found that you had multiple buffers overflows. The problem was that you tried to access an array with an index of its length to get the last element, like this: `arr[n]` if `n` is the length of `arr`. The problem is that arrays start at index 0, so to get the last element you must use `arr[n-1]`.

Another thing to remember is that to loop over an array use `<=`, not `<`. This is also because arrays start at 0.

Here is your code with the buffer overflows fixed:

```cpp
#include <limits.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int helper(int* arr, int n, int pos) {
  int r = pos + 2, l = pos - 2, ans = 0;
  while (r < n) {
    ans += arr[r] * arr[r - 1] * arr[pos];
    r++;
  }

  while (l >= 0) {
    ans += arr[l] * arr[l + 1] * arr[pos];
    l--;
  }

  if (pos != 0 && pos != n) {
    ans += arr[pos] * arr[0] * arr[n - 1];
  }
  return ans;
}

int matrixChainMultiplication(int* arr, int n) {
  int ans = INT_MAX;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ans = min(ans, helper(arr, n, i));
  }
  return ans;
}

int main() {
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  int* arr = new int[n];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> arr[i];
  }

  cout << matrixChainMultiplication(arr, n);

  delete[] arr;
}
```